# How can make filter case insensitive lambda expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. I'm doing filter with the below function. My search result is always sensitive for a string value. For employee name, it would be case-insensitive search, so user can enter upper or lowercase `searchValue`. My list is converted **ToList()** to **AsQueryable()**

```
list = list.Where(AppendFilters<CustomerApiResponse>(data.filter.filters));
```

Please see the below function:

```
protected ExpressionStarter<T> AppendFilters<T>(List<Filter2> filters)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();

    foreach (var item in filters)
    {
        predicate = predicate.And(GetExpression<T>(item.field, item.value, item.@operator));
    }

    return predicate;
}
```

Here's what I have:

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(string propName, object val, string op)
{
    ParameterExpression argParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var nameProperty = Expression.Property(argParam, propName);
    var opp = EnumExtensions.ParseEnum<KendoOperators>(op).GetDescription();

    MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod(opp, new[] { typeof(string) });
    Expression e1;

    if (nameProperty.Type == typeof(int))
    {
        var propertyType = ((PropertyInfo)nameProperty.Member).PropertyType;
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propertyType);

        if (!converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
            throw new NotSupportedException();

        var propertyValue = converter.ConvertFrom(val); 
        var constant = Expression.Constant(propertyValue);
        var valueExpression = Expression.Convert(constant, propertyType);

        if (op == "neq")
        {
            e1 = Expression.NotEqual(nameProperty, valueExpression);
        }
        else
        {
            e1 = Expression.Equal(nameProperty, valueExpression);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var constant = Expression.Constant(val);

        e1 = Expression.Call(nameProperty, method, constant);
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(e1, argParam);
}
```

How do I change the above code to make filter to be case-insensitive for searches any string value?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the resultant `method` value that is called?

Comment: sorry I'm not getting you. I'm filtering list (CustomerApiResponse) , there have customer information. Thanks !

Comment: You have `var opp = `... and then `MethodInfo method = `... - what is the value of `opp` and `method` for your string comparison?

Comment: string propName="Name", object val="Marie", string op="Contains " 
var opp = Contains ,
Name is table column name. Thanks !

Comment: My list is AsQueryable()